# Create new profile while Firefox is running?

Tags: firefox

With Firefox you can [create a new profile](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) from the command line

```
firefox -CreateProfile JoelUser
```

However I have found that this only works when Firefox is closed. If Firefox is open the command merely opens a new window, and does nothing more.

I can work around this by manually creating the folder and editing `profiles.ini`, but should it work from the command line as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something of a workaround is to invoke Firefox like this

```
firefox -no-remote -profile JoelUser
```

This will create a new profile in the current directory, then launch Firefox.